# VSCode Python terminal forced to use exit() command

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run python files in VSCode and I'm running into an issue after the program ends.
Ex. code:

```
# simple code
print(":(")
```

I have to type exit() every time I want to run code again, since the code finishes and the console shows >>> instead of the typical text (Computer name:Folder Username$).

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Details:
Extensions active: Python (Microsoft), Jupyter, Pylance

Edit: Running files with python3 myFile.py in terminal (the real mac one and the VSCode one) works perfectly fine, but I have to escape with exit() when clicking the green run button.

Comment: do You run the code in terminal (does vscode even have that in the way I imagine? (similarly to PyCharm))?

Comment: You are running the script file on terminal (It is taking line by line copy from your file to terminal for execution). Execute the script file using `python3` command. Like, `python3 myFile.py`

Comment: Thanks, that works! If anyone knows why the green run button (provided through the Microsoft python extension) ends in >>> and doesn't fully "stop", let me know!

Comment: @user16434793 hi, friend, the problem has been solved?

Comment: Yes pretty much! For some reason, I still have to call exit() if I use the green run button (through the Python extension), so if you happen to know why that happens I'd love to know. Otherwise, using `python3` will do just fine.